# Unable to download depencencies in virtual environment

Tags: python, windows, pip

Hope you're doing well,
I was trying to work on this django project from github but i could not download all the packages in a virtual environment, it says

```
(venv) C:\Users\me\Downloads\movie_recommender-master>pip install -r requirements.txt
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe "C:\Users\me\Downloads\movie_recommender-master\venv\Scripts\pip.exe" install -r requirements.txt'
```

. I have read through tons of questions in stack over flow but nothing seems to work, I would be very grateful if you could help me here.

[image: My command prompt says this]

Comment: What's the output of `pip --version`

Comment: And output of `where pip` and `where python` if you are running Windows?

Comment: Hey guys, @codepylot and @Branko I appreciate the responses
the output of  `pip --version` is 
`pip 21.3.1 from C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)`
`where pip` gives the output
`C:\Users\me\pip`
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe`
`where python` gives the ouput
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe`
`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`

Comment: Have you activated your virtual environment?

Comment: have a look at this [post](https://exerror.com/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using/#Solution_3_Just_update_pip) my guess you may need to update `pip` to do that just run this command `pip list` and you will find the full command to update the **local pip** just copy and paste it.

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic yes sir i did i went into the directory and typed `virtualenv -p python3 venv`  and then activated it by `venv\Scripts\activate`
i downloaded the project again to do the process again, Here's the link https://imgur.com/a/e1wcwdX
I appreciate you taking your time to help me :)

Comment: @cizario I typed `pip list` and it showed 


`C:\Users\me>pip list
Package                           Version
--------------------------------- -------
backports.entry-points-selectable 1.1.0
distlib                           0.3.3
filelock                          3.3.1
pip                               21.3.1
platformdirs                      2.4.0
setuptools                        57.4.0
six                               1.16.0
virtualenv                        20.8.1
wheel                             0.37.0`
 so i tried to upgrade pip  but https://imgur.com/a/TeSU4dk

Comment: @D023, it's clear `pip` is already up to date, in fact I used first to update `pip` when I run this command `py -m venv venv`, `venv` is the python build-in module to create an isolated virtual environment without the need of any 3rd apps/tools.

Comment: @cizario i dont why im getting `unable to create process` error

Comment: @D023, i have absolutely no glue but try to create the virtual environment using this command `py -m venv venv` (since you are on windows, note: `py` is located under `c: \Windows` after a successful python install) maybe there a problem with the command `virtualenv -p python3 venv` head over this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69604088/12368419)

Comment: What is your working directory where your code is located?

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic it is located at `C:\Users\Joydeep Paul\Downloads\movie_recommender-master`

Comment: And your virtual environment is in subdirectory venv @D023?

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic Yes sir thats correct

Answer (score 0):

From all answers in comments I would say that it is quite clear - you are not activating your virtual environment or it is not setup correctly.

As I can understand from your text and comments your working directory is:

```
C:\Users\Joydeep Paul\Downloads\movie_recommender-master
```

and your virtual environment is at:

```
C:\Users\Joydeep Paul\Downloads\movie_recommender-master\venv
```

When you issue this commands:

```
where pip
where python
```

they need to point to your virtual environment (after you activate it with activate command) but instead they point to system wide versions:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
```

So to answer your question, one of the following has happened:

- your system wide python installation is bad and it does not correctly setup virtual environment in your project
- you haven't activated your virtual environment (although you say that you did)
- there is some major issue with your windows installation or privileges

Maybe you can try to deactivate vritual environment issue where python3 statement and then activate it again and try once more where command?