# Cant Install pipx or Brownie for Python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip, brownie, pipx

I am very new with coding and was following along with these youtube videos and quickly realized something wasn't right, so I did some trouble shooting and couldn't figure it out.

When I tried to download `pipx` on `VS Code` I get this error

[image]

```
Python3 : The term 'Python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I changed my environment variables, changed app execution aliases, and still nothing

I figured I'd check to see if python was working through `VS Code` and I get the same error

I tried downloading python through Microsoft store to see if that would help but nope.

Not sure what to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69604088/12368419

Comment: Can you please post your code and not a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue for a while even though I added the following directory to the environment variable and system variable. C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx

What worked for me was adding the following directory to the environment variable and system variable.  (c:\users\username.local\bin)

The directory (c:\users\username.local\bin) will be used to create the virtual environments.

I also found this when typing (python -m pipx ensurepath) which returned:

```
C:\Users\username\.local\bin has been been added to PATH, but you need to open a new terminal or re-login for this PATH change
    to take effect.
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts has been been added to PATH, but you need to open a new terminal or
    re-login for this PATH change to take effect.
```

The (C:\Users\username.local\bin) path was the only thing I did not manually enter into my environment variable and system variable, so thought I should give that a try and it worked.