# Can't install packages in virtual environment created with venv

Tags: python, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-venv

I am developing in the following environment:

- Windows11 21H2.
- Ubuntu-20.04
- Visual Studio Code 2022
- Remote-WSL extension in VSCode
- Python3.8.10 64-bit

I formatted a USB drive in NTFS format and installed Django in the virtual environment with the following procedure:

```
sudo python3 -m venv .venv
sudo source .venv/bin/activate
sudo python3 -m pip install django
```

Originally, the version should be displayed when `sudo python3 -m django --version` is executed, but `No module named django` is displayed.

How can I install packages for each virtual environment?

As a result of checking, it seems that it is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/` even if (.venv) is displayed at the tip of the command line.

Comment: Why use `sudo`? Is that on purpose? -- If I recall correctly, each `sudo` command is independent, when `sudo source .venv/bin/activate` finishes, everything about the "activation" of the virtual environment is forgotten.

Comment: If you really have to, then you can skip the activation step and do `sudo .venv/bin/python -m pip install django` instead. -- But again, I find it surprising that you would want to use`sudo` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `sudo` is problematic here.  There are a few problems with using `sudo` with a venv in this case:

- *Typically*, `sudo python3 -m venv .venv` would create the venv as root, but you mention that you are doing this on an NTFS-formatted USB drive.  Because of the way that WSL accesses NTFS drives, all files on the NTFS drive will be owned by your default WSL user anyway, so `sudo` really has no effect here.

  If you were doing this on the ext4 filesystem that WSL provides, *then* the venv files would be owned by root.  It's likely that this could then cause additional problems because of the VSCode issue described below.
- VSCode, as well, always runs WSL as your default user.  Really, WSL always runs VSCode (and any other Windows application) as your default user.  Because of this, when inside VSCode, tools such as the Python extension will be accessing the venv as your default user, potentially leading to permissions issues if VSCode (or an extension) attempt to modify anything in it.
- Then there's `sudo source .venv/bin/activate`, which should just be giving you an error, plain and simple.

  - `sudo` runs *applications* in Linux.
  - `source` is a Bash *builtin*, not an application itself.

  As a result, you should be receiving:

  ```
  sudo: source: command not found
  ```

  ... when attempting that.  I'm guessing you are skipping `sudo` on that command to work around it, but forgot to leave it off in the question?
- Finally, the biggest problem here is that venv works by modifying the environment of the current shell when you `activate`.  This is why `source` is required.  One of the key environment variables that is modified, of course, is the `PATH`, so that when you call `python3` or `pip3`, it uses the one from the virtual environment.

  However, for security reasons, `sudo` does *not*, by default, allow the `PATH` to be propagated to the environment running inside it.  You can run `sudo -Es` to run a shell with the *other* environment variables propagated, but the `PATH` will still be the default for root.  Changing this is possible, via `visudo`, but not recommended for security reasons.

  This is the primary reason that your packages are being installed in the global/system environment, rather than in your virtual environment.

All-in-all, using `sudo` here is not going to be a good plan.  Use your default user for the venv, VSCode, and WSL and things should work (more) as expected.

- Side-issue:  You don't mention WSL2, but it's the default for most installations.  Under WSL2, even `python3 -venv .venv` is going to be *very* slow on an NTFS drive for the reasons I mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974497/11810933).  It's highly recommended, if possible, to either keep your project on WSL2's ext4 filesystem.  If you are using WSL1, then this does not apply.

Comment: However, If I'm not using `sudo`, I'm recieving this error:  `Error: Command '['/mnt/h/python/test002/.venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`As shown in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594088/error-when-creating-venv-error-command-im-ensurepip-upgrade-def), so I think I have to use `sudo`.This error does not occur on C drive. Is it not possible to use a mounted USB drive?

Comment: @Static Ahh.  I see.  No, you don't need to use `sudo`; you just need to make sure the USB drive is mounted properly under WSL.  See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1736246/1210833) for my recommend mount settings.  Otherwise, yes, the USB drive is mounted as root-owned, and it will cause issues.  Try the `mount` command I recommend in that Super User answer and let me know if that changes things for you.

Comment: It's kind of odd, I know, that [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1209698/1210833) has 141 upvotes, but is the reason you are having the problem, I think.

Comment: It worked!
My problem was to do like [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1114341/windows-10-ubuntu-bash-shell-how-do-i-mount-other-windows-drives/1209698#1209698).