# create an virtual enviroment from python script

Tags: python, windows, python-venv

I have a python script that downloads projects out of git.
This script runs inside a virtual enviroment
( for example: d:\robot_fw\venv\cloner\Scripts\python.exe)
After cloning the repo I itend to create a new virtual enviroment, with
all depencies needed for the cloned project.

From the python script I used

```
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "venv", self.virtual_dir])
# sys.executable is d:\\robot_fw\\venv\\cloner\\Scripts\\python.exe
# self.virtual_dir is 'd:\\itxvenv\\venv\\myvenv'
```

The call was successfull. But when I check the directory I find:
d:\itxvenv\venv\myvenv\Scripts and in this dir only python.exe and pythonw.exe
The venv could not be activated

If I do the same call from inside a terminal ( terminal insode pycharm)

```
(cloner) PS D:\Development\Dev\cloner> d:\\robot_fw\\venv\\cloner\\Scripts\\python.exe -m venv d:\\itxvenv\\venv\\myvenv
```

I found

```
enter code here


ode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          21.02.2023    21:16           2066 activate
-a---          21.02.2023    21:16            995 activate.bat
-a---          21.02.2023    21:16          24167 Activate.ps1
-a---          21.02.2023    21:16            393 deactivate.bat
-a---          21.02.2023    21:16         107888 pip.exe
-a---          21.02.2023    21:16         107888 pip3.10.exe
-a---          21.02.2023    21:16         107888 pip3.exe
-a---          21.02.2023    21:16         266616 python.exe
-a---          21.02.2023    21:16         254840 pythonw.exe
```

This could be actiavted.

So whats going wrong here?

Comment: just for the record - I tested it as is under Linux, it just works. I think it is possible that the venv creation gets caught, even if indirectly, by Windows "a file can only be open by one process at a time"  default policy when trying this.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `subprocess`. Create the virtual environment directly from the `venv` module:

```
import venv

venv.create(self.virtual_dir)
```

Comment: ok, did not now that this exists. Will try this in the morning

Comment: if I use this venv.create(self.virtual_dir, with_pip=True)
I received
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thorsten.guddack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['d:\\itxvenv\\venv\\myvenv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: Does `python3-setuptools` is installed in your current environnment? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594088/error-when-creating-venv-error-command-im-ensurepip-upgrade-def

Comment: Switches off the PC now. But of i did IT from the cmd line, python - m venv... IT works. Does this means hat the mentioned packages were installed?

Comment: yes setup tools is installed.